# Laravel Cashier Checkout results in an empty page

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am having an issue with Laravel Cashier. I am trying to use their checkout functionality that should redirect to a Stripe checkout page, however it does not. It returns a blank page as if it were a get request.

**Note, this is a subscription checkout, not a product checkout**

Notes: I recently upgraded this application to Laravel 6 from 5.8 and Cashier to 12.17.2 from 10.2 so I could get the checkout functionality which was introduced in Cashier 12.7

The blade page just has a form and a submit button that posts to the subscription.create route.

That route has the following code, but when it executes it does not load a Stripe checkout page, it loads a blank page at the /subscription endpoint. This is set up as a POST route in web.php pointing to the correct function

Note, the variables being passed to the newSubscription function have been changed, they are correct in the actual code

```
    Route::get('/subscription-checkout', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user()
        ->newSubscription('default', 'plan')
        ->allowPromotionCodes()
        ->checkout([
          'success_url' => route('thankyou'),
          'cancel_url' => route('home'),
        ]);
    })->name('subscription.create');
```

**Update** - So it is returning a JSON object to the page, but it is never redirecting to the payment page as it is supposed to. The JSON object contains the payment page URL....

This is very confusing.

Comment: Can you do 3 things, 1- do a `dd($request->all())` and 2- change 'plan' to $plan, then 3- what exactly are you checkingout? checkout requires 2 arrays, the result is the 2nd array which is what you did, but you are missing the first array of checking out something https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/billing#product-checkouts it would be easier to get a better idea of how you are doing things.

Comment: 1. dumping $request->all() gives exactly what I expect it to. Basically just the plan id
2. as noted, "plan" is just here, the plan in the actual code is $plan->id
3. I realize I made an error not saying this is a subscription checkout not a product checkout, which is slightly different and doesn't require arrays, just the description and the Stripe subscription ID

Comment: I just realized you are not returning anything, add `return $request->user()....`

Comment: @KGG That will return the JSON object to the page, it still doesn't redirect to the Stripe checkout as Cashier claims it should. Thanks though.

Comment: @RickCalder if you are already getting the actual stripe checkout page URL in the response. I think theres not much of a problem, just redirect to that url instead of returning the checkout object `return redirect()->to( 'stripe-checkout-url' )->send();`

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you are calling the `checkout` on a `create` method. and its showing blank because you are not returning anything.

you have to define a route which returns that checkout process (which then redirects to stripe checkout page).

Something like

```
Route::get('/sub', function (Request $request) {

    return $request->user()
        ->newSubscription('Subscription', 'plan')
        ->allowPromotionCodes()
        ->checkout([
            'success_url' => route('thankyou'),
            'cancel_url' => route('home'),
        ]);
});
```

the `checkout` method of cashier is just a wrapper of stripe checkout which you have to pass in the data of what you trying to checkout, you can see [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart) full example from Stripe

**EDIT:**

if the object you getting from the response is actual stripe `checkout` object, you could simply grab the checkout url and redirect to it. if not then you might be able to do your own checkout session assuming your cashier version supports checkout session.

Something like

```
Route::get('/sub', function (Request $request) {

    $checkout =  $request->user()->stripe()->checkout->sessions->create([
        'customer_email' => $request->user()->email,
        'line_items' => [[
            'price' => 'SUBSCRIPTION_ID',
            'quantity' => 1,
        ]],
        'mode' => 'subscription',
        'success_url' => route('thankyou'),
        'cancel_url' => route('home')
    ]);

    //return $checkout; //checkout session response.

    return redirect()->to( $checkout->url )->send();

});
```

Comment: That still does not redirect, it just returns the JSON object that Stripe creates. That object contains the URL for the checkout page, but somehow Cashier is not actually doing the redirect.

Comment: if you are already returning the checkout instance, the response should have 303 redirect header. otherwise, try doing clean Laravel 6 install with nothing but cashier to test the code Ive pasted above and see if it still not redirecting as Im not sure if that would work with laravel 6

Comment: According to Cashier the version I am running still supports Laravel 6, but perhaps not this particular feature :(

Comment: maybe just build your own checkout session, based on that stripe example.

Comment: @RickCalder Yeah, checkout was introduced in laravel 8 :( https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#checkout

Comment: @KGG damn, okay, 2 more upgrades.... yay. Thanks!

Comment: @RickCalder, I edited my answer, you might want to check and see if you can create your own checkout session

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out Cashier 12.7 works on Laravel 6
But Checkout only works on 8 and above.